# How to disable AutoPlay video in youtube Player Api in Android in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am unable to disable the auto play video in youtube I tried many ways to disable but none of effort worked. How can I disable the video using youtube Api android?

```
    fun playVideo(videoId: String){
        qHandlernew?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        var startPoint =
            Uri.parse(videoId)
                .getQueryParameter("start")
        var endPoint: String? =
            Uri.parse(videoId)
                .getQueryParameter("end")

        val part =
            videoId.substring(0, videoId.lastIndexOf('?'))
        val youtubeId = part.substring(part.length - 11, part.length)
        if (startPoint == null)
            player?.loadVideo(youtubeId)
        else
            player?.loadVideo(
                youtubeId,
                Integer.parseInt(startPoint) * 1000
            )
        Log.d("videosCheck", "onInitializationSuccess: $videoId")
        if (endPoint != null) {

            qHandlernew = Handler()
            qHandlernew!!.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    //For every 1 second, check the current time and endTime
                    if (player?.currentTimeMillis!! <= Integer.parseInt(
                            endPoint
                        ) * 1000
                    ) {
                        qHandlernew!!.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                    } else {
                        qHandlernew!!.removeCallbacks(this) //no longer required
                        player?.pause() //and Pause the video
                    }
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply do `cueVideo(your video id)` instead of `loadVideo(your Video id)`

```
fun playVideo(videoId: String){
    qHandlernew?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    var startPoint =
        Uri.parse(videoId)
            .getQueryParameter("start")
    var endPoint: String? =
        Uri.parse(videoId)
            .getQueryParameter("end")

    val part =
        videoId.substring(0, videoId.lastIndexOf('?'))
    val youtubeId = part.substring(part.length - 11, part.length)
    if (startPoint == null)
        player?.cueVideo(youtubeId)
    else
        player?.cueVideo(
            youtubeId,
            Integer.parseInt(startPoint) * 1000
        )
    Log.d("videosCheck", "onInitializationSuccess: $videoId")
    if (endPoint != null) {

        qHandlernew = Handler()
        qHandlernew!!.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                //For every 1 second, check the current time and endTime
                if (player?.currentTimeMillis!! <= Integer.parseInt(
                        endPoint
                    ) * 1000
                ) {
                    qHandlernew!!.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                } else {
                    qHandlernew!!.removeCallbacks(this) //no longer required
                    player?.pause() //and Pause the video
                }
            }
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```